# Efficient multiclass SVM package

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm, svmlight

Do you guys have experience with an efficient multiclass SVM package? I am currently using libsvm, but on 300k instances and 200 features it takes a very long time (24+ hours) to train.

Thanks!

Comment: what kind of kernel do you need?

Comment: Try this: http://www.loria.fr/~lauer/MSVMpack/
It is very user friendly and uses all available cores on the machine.

Comment: I am using a RBF kernel. Thanks soufanom for the pointer, I will check out MSVMpack.

Answer (score 0):

With that dimension and that many examples you might not be in luck using an RBF kernel. I would give it a try with the linear kernel or with LIBLINEAR (http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/)